# Add Right Click Event to Full calender Angular JS Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, contextmenu

I am using the Angular UI Calender API in my MVC Project

**UI Calender API** [http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/]

I want to add right click Context Menu to it.On clicking any date or Event the context Menu should appear containing link options

1.Add Appointment
2.Add Meeting
3.Add Task

I have used the Bootstrap Context Menu https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu

The Problem I am facing is on right click the context menu is appearing the event does not captures the Date and Event details from the Calender which i need to pass to show in a POP UP.

I have used below code in my Angular Js Controller.

```
var calendarDemoApp = angular.module('myCalendarApp', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.contextMenu']);

calendarDemoApp.controller('CalendarCtrl',
  function ($scope, $http,$compile, $timeout, uiCalendarConfig) {
   
   $scope.SelectedEvent = null;
   var isFirstTime = true;`enter code here`

   $scope.events = [];
   $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

   //Load events from server
   $http.get('/home/getevents', {
       cache: true,
       params: {}
   }).then(function (data) {
       $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
       angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
           $scope.events.push({
               title: value.Title,
               description: value.Description,
               start: new Date(parseInt(value.StartAt.substr(6))),
               end: new Date(parseInt(value.EndAt.substr(6))),
               allDay: value.IsFullDay,
               stick: true
           });
       });
   });
          /* alert on eventClick */
   $scope.alertOnEventClick = function (date, jsEvent, view) {
       $scope.alertMessage = (date.title + ' was clicked ');
   };
   /* alert on Drop */
   $scope.alertOnDrop = function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
       $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Dropped to make dayDelta ' + delta);
   };
   /* alert on Resize */
   $scope.alertOnResize = function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
       $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Resized to make dayDelta ' + delta);
   };
   /* add and removes an event source of choice */
   $scope.addRemoveEventSource = function (sources, source) {
       var canAdd = 0;
       angular.forEach(sources, function (value, key) {
           if (sources[key] === source) {
               sources.splice(key, 1);
               canAdd = 1;
           }
       });
       if (canAdd === 0) {
           sources.push(source);
       }
   };
   /* add custom event*/
   $scope.addEvent = function () {
      
   };
   /* remove event */
   $scope.remove = function (index) {
       $scope.events.splice(index, 1);
   };
   /* Change View */
   $scope.changeView = function (view, calendar) {          
       uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView', view);
   };
   /* Change View */
   $scope.renderCalendar = function (calendar) {
       $timeout(function () {
           if (uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar]) {
               uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');
           }
       });
   };
   /*COntext Menu*/
   var AppointmentHtml = '<div style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>New Appointment</div>';
   var AppointmentItem = {
       html: AppointmentHtml, click: function ($itemScope, event, modelValue, text, $li, date, jsEvent, view) {
           debugger;
           var winH = $(window).height();
           var winW = $(window).width();

           $.ajax({
               url: '/Home/Appointment',
               data: {},
               cache: false,
               success: function (result) {
                   //alert(result);
                   $("#dialog-content").html(result);
                   $("#divEdit").dialog({
                       modal: true,
                       title: 'Add Appointment',
                       close: function (event, ui) {
                           $(this).dialog('destroy');
                       }
                   });
                   $(".ui-dialog").css({ 'min-width': '600px', 'left': winW / 2 - 300 });


               },
               error: function (request, status, error) {
                   alert(status);
               }
           });
       }
   };
   var MeetingHtml = '<div style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>New Meeting</div>';
   var MeetingItem = {
       html: MeetingHtml, click: function ($itemScope, event, modelValue, text, $li) {
           alert("New Appointment");
           console.info($itemScope);
           console.info(event);
           console.info(modelValue);
           console.info(text);
           console.info($li);
       }
   };
   var TaskHtml = '<div style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i>New Task</div>';
   var TaskItem = {
       html: TaskHtml, click: function ($itemScope, event, modelValue, text, $li) {
           alert("New Task");
           console.info($itemScope);
           console.info(event);
           console.info(modelValue);
           console.info(text);
           console.info($li);
       }
   };

   

   $scope.customHTMLOptions = [AppointmentItem, MeetingItem,
       TaskItem
   ];

   /* Render Tooltip */
   $scope.eventRender = function (event, element, view) {
       element.attr({
           'tooltip': event.title,
           'tooltip-append-to-body': true
       });
       $compile(element)($scope);
   };
   /* config object */
   $scope.uiConfig = {
       calendar: {
           height: 450,
           editable: true,
           header: {
               left: 'title',
               center: '',
               right: 'today prev,next'
           },
           eventClick: function (event) {
               $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
           },
           eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
           eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
           eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
           eventAfterAllRender: function () {
               if ($scope.events.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                   //Focus first event
                   uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
                   isFirstTime = false;
               }
           }
       }
   };

   $scope.changeLang = function () {
       if ($scope.changeTo === 'Hungarian') {
           $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNames = ["Vasárnap", "Hétfő", "Kedd", "Szerda", "Csütörtök", "Péntek", "Szombat"];
           $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNamesShort = ["Vas", "Hét", "Kedd", "Sze", "Csüt", "Pén", "Szo"];
           $scope.changeTo = 'English';
       } else {
           $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
           $scope.uiConfig.calendar.dayNamesShort = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
           $scope.changeTo = 'Hungarian';
       }
   };
   /* event sources array*/
   //$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.eventSource, $scope.eventsF];
   //$scope.eventSources2 = [$scope.calEventsExt, $scope.eventsF, $scope.events];
});
```

Below is my HTML Code:

```
<section id="directives-calendar" ng-controller="CalendarCtrl">
    <div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar" context-menu="customHTMLOptions" config="uiConfig.calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
</Section>
```

Comment: <div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar" context-menu="customHTMLOptions" config="uiConfig.calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>